# Lua: attempt to call global 'rectangle_draw' (a nil value)

Tags: function, lua, love2d

I have two Lua files, one of which is **main.lua**:

```
require "player"
require "level"

function love.load()

end

function love.draw()
    rectangle_draw()
end
```

and another called **player.lua**:

```
function rectangle_draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(223, 202, 79)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 20, 20, 32, 48)
end
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the `rectangle_draw()` inside of `love.draw()` function, hoping it to draw a rectangle in specific location etc etc, but whenever I try to run my little program I get this error:

```
attempt to call global 'rectangle_draw' (a nil value)

Traceback

main.lua:9: in function 'draw'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not exporting any functions from `player.lua`. The correct way would be to do it like this:

**player.lua**

```
local M = {}

function M.rectangle_draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(223, 202, 79)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 20, 20, 32, 48)
end

return M
```

**main.lua**

```
local player = require "player"
require "level"

function love.load()

end

function love.draw()
    player.rectangle_draw()
end
```

---

Please see [this section](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-require) of the Lua manual, and [this page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModuleDefinition) on the Lua users wiki for more information about how modules and `require` work.